# How to check that a string contains characters other than those specified. (in Java)

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a program that asks the user to input a three character string. The string can only be a combination of a, b, or c.

How do I check if the string contains any other characters than those specified without doing a million conditional statements.

Pseudo example:

```
String s = "abq"

if (s.containsOtherCharacterThan(a,b,c))
    System.exit(-1)
```

Comment: Use regex to achieve that.

Comment: how is this not a real question? it is just what i was looking for

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To look for characters that are NOT a, b, or c, use something like the following:

```
if(!s.matches("[abc]+"))
{
    System.out.println("The string you entered has some incorrect characters");
}
```

Comment: Its actually you're regex which seems to be failing. `System.out.println("abq".matches("[^abc]"));` gave me `false`, where it should have given `true`.

Comment: @Indigenuity - `System.out.println("abq".matches("[^abc]+"));` still gives `false`. I don't wanna sound EVIL, but since this answer has been accepted, you better put a working solution, as other people may refer it. I suggest you run the code in your IDE and paste it from there.

Comment: @R.J - Changed answer to the expression you gave

Comment: @J.L.Louis - check the updated answer - which you accepted. This is the correct verison ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can use regex and its [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Just invoke [`String#matches(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) on string you want to check if it can be matched entirely by regex.

```
if (!s.matches("[abc]+")) {//..
```

This test should pass only strings that contains also other characters then specified in `[` `]` so `"abq"` should pass it since it contains `q`. Matches will check if `s` contains only `a`, `b`, and `c` characters. If not it will will return `false`, and thanks to negation we will enter in if block.

Comment: I'm not the best at regex, but I think this will just tell you if NONE of the characters are the allowed characters.

Comment: @Indigenuity is right - that regular expression would pass the failing example `abq`.

Comment: I stand corrected.  You are right

Comment: @Pshemo: you say "Matches will check if s contains only a, b, and c characters", but that's not what your pattern will check for. Maybe you want to say something like `^[abc]+$`, which tests the entire string, but as stated, the `.matches()` method will return true for `abq`, as the pattern will successfully match the `ab` portion of the string.

Comment: @Stobor matches by default checks entire string so `^` `$` in this case are not necessary. `System.out.println("abq".matches("[abc]+"))` prints `false`

Comment: @Pshemo - interesting; been too long since I used regex in Java, apparently I've forgotten that detail.

Comment: @Stobor No problem. I just hope that OP will figure out that answer he/she accepted wasn't correct and will see its updated version :)

Answer (score 3):

You could split the string into an array and loop through the input from there you could compare each character.

```
public boolean containsOtherCharacter(String s, String a, String b, String c) {
    String[] st = s.split("");
    for(int x = 0; x < st.length; x++)
        if (st[x].compareTo(a) != 0 && st[x].compareTo(b) != 0 && st[x].compareTo(c) != 0)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

This will tell you if there are any other characters. If you would like to know which characters they are, you could insert each character into a HashMap where the key is the character and the value is the number of times it is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression:- `[abc]+`.

Comment: That regular expression would pass his failing test case `abq`.

Comment: I really doubt that. `abq` won't match the pattern `[abc]+`.

Comment: `[abc]+` will match the `ab` from `abq`, so `"abq".match("[abc]+")` will return `true`    EDIT I stand corrected.  You are right

Comment: Yep - the pattern `[abc]+` means 'any of the letters a, b or c, 1 or more times', which will match the `ab` portion of `abq`.

Comment: Firstly, there is no `match` method in the `String` class. Secondly, only after trying them out in my IDE, I've posted it. For your convenience, try to run this code, and see what you get. `System.out.println("abq".matches("[abc]+"));`

Comment: I got `false` as the answer.

Comment: @Stobor - Still any doubts with the regex?

Comment: @R.J sorry, I got distracted; I went and checked it before, but didn't get to come back and update here. Yeah, I forgot that Java implicitly puts the `^` and `$` around the expression if you use `.matches()` - so the regex as you stated does work there.

Answer (score 1):

A way without regex would be to loop through the string and check each character, exiting if the character is anything but a, b, or c. There is no way to do it just with String.contains